# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver has no segue with identifier 'unwind''

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

when user clicked button

```
let uvc: UINavigationController =
            self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nationSelect") as! UINavigationController

uvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
self.present(uvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

run this code.

[identifier:nationSelect storyboard img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8OCt.png)

[cell, closebutton, VC segue unwind  img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkygR.png)

and
button vc have this function

```
@IBAction func unwindFromPostCodeSelectionView(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("unwindFromPostCodeSelectionView")
}
```

and nationSelect VC

when collectionview's cell clicked 
run this code

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: unwind, sender: nil)
```

and prepare function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier == unwind else{
        return
    }
    guard let vc = segue.destination as? CurationRequestViewController else {
        return
    }

    vc.getAddress.setTitle( (continent.text ?? " ") + " " + nation , for: .normal)
}
```

but i got this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'unwind''**

help me plz!!!

Comment: what is unwind ? where did you define this ?

Comment: I think you have omitted an identifier. Give the identifier to it and check by using `if-statement` : `if segue.identifier == "yourId" { // Do something }`

Comment: @ShauketSheikh unwind is String in nationSelect ViewController

Comment: check unwind is an option string ? if it is option then change it to normal one.

Comment: unwind String is define let

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to implement unwind segue and you missed to specify the identifier for unwind segue.

Here are the steps to properly implement unwind segue:

**Step 1:** If you are trying to implement unwind segue from Vc2 to Vc1 (Coming back to VC1 from VC2) then in VC1 add the `IBAction` as

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewController1(segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {
     //you will get control back here when you unwind
}
```

**Step 2:**
Open storyboard, select VC2 and control drag from ViewController to Exit option in storyboard as shown below

[image]

This should show a popover and the method you just declared select it.

**Step 3: (Step I think you missed)**
Select the unwind segue you just added and provide a identifier to it.

[image]

**Step 4:**
Now whenever you wanna return back to VC1 you can simply call

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToViewController1", sender: nil)
```

Hope it helps :) Happy coding

Comment: Excellent description! Thank you for reminding the correct procedure :)